# What is the meaning of apache camel Unit Of Work?

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to camel and trying to understand the concept of UoW in apache camel. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: UoW is also covered in much more details in some of the Camel books such as the Camel in Action 1st and 2nd edition books.

Answer (score 1):

From Camel 2.14 onwards the onCompletion has been modified to support running the completion task in either synchronous or asynchronous mode (using a thread pool) and also whether to run before or after the route consumer is done. The reason is to give more flexibility. For example to specify to run synchronous and before the route consumer is done, which allows to modify the exchange before the consumer writes back any response to the callee. You can use this to for example add customer headers, or send to a log to log the response message, etc.

Here is the link to it:

[Apache Camel UoW](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html)

Answer (score 1):

Below a scenario that helped me understand what is Unit Of Work.

If you use:

```
onException(..)
    .useOriginalMessage()
    ..
```

in your configuration, then the Unit Of Work in exchange will contain the original body and in case of an exception, the original message will be sent to a dead letter queue.

However if you then use a `.split()` in your route, something like:

```
.from(..)
    .split()
    .body()
    .to("mock:b")
    ..
```

then for each part of the split a new Unit Of Work will be created, probably with a different body (depends on what you split). In case of an exception, body from the new Unit Of Work will be sent to dead letter queue, not the original one. You must expect it to be original because you specified `.useOriginalMessage()` but this won't happen. To get the expected behavior add `.shareUnitOfWork()` to your route like so:

```
    .from(..)
    .split()
    .body()
    .shareUnitOfWork()
    .to("mock:b")
    ..
```

Now each failed message that goes into dead letter queue will be the original one.

Answer (score -2):

An object representing the unit of work processing an "exchange" which allows the use of Synchronization hooks. This object might map one-to-one with a transaction in JPA or Spring, or might not.